# In a locally run web app, is there any performance hit from loading fonts?

Tags: css, performance, fonts, electron, webfonts

So it's common knowledge that if you load like 100 fonts from, say, Google Fonts, then it will probably cause some loading performance issues on your site. But it's not totally clear to me if almost all of that performance hit is just from downloading from Google, or if it's partially due to just having to parse through the various fonts.

I'm currently building an Electron app meant to be run locally. If I package fonts within the app and load them, will I have to worry about any load times from parsing/loading the font files?

Comment: If the font mentioned in your application is not available in host pc/desktop, then only it will download from external resources. Please check the performance of your application by installing the fonts and without fonts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dev tools on your webpage. Go to the network tab and see how long each resource takes to load.